# When click status bar Notification (Phonegap PushPlugin) The application is launched but does not detect coldstart state

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, push-notification

I am developing an android application in eclipse and I have successfully installed the Phonegap PushPlugin, everything works perfectly, notifications are received and launched in the status bar and they open my application when touched.

The problem comes when my application is off (meaning coldstate) , the application is launched successfully but does not run the action inside the "if ( e.coldstart )"

I wrote my code based on the following example published in the official documentation of the plugin:

```
function onNotificationGCM(e) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> RECEIVED:' + e.event + '</li>');
    switch (e.event) {
    case 'registered':
        if (e.regid.length > 0) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>REGISTERED -> REGID:' + e.regid + "</li>");
            // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
            // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
            console.log("regID = " + e.regid);
        }
        break;
    case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
        if (e.foreground) {
            $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--INLINE NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            // if the notification contains a soundname, play it.
            var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + e.soundname);
            my_media.play();
        } else { // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
            if (e.coldstart) {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            } else {
                $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
            }
        }
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + e.payload.message + '</li>');
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + e.payload.msgcnt + '</li>');
        break;
    case 'error':
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>ERROR -> MSG:' + e.msg + '</li>');
        break;
    default:
        $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>EVENT -> Unknown, an event was received and we do not know what it is</li>');
        break;
    }
}
```

This code is on the main page of my application that opens when you tap the notification and successfully show labels "INLINE NOTIFICATION" and "BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION" whichever is applicable

Not supposed to so place within the

```
if (e.coldstart) {
    $("#app-status-ul").append('<li>--COLDSTART NOTIFICATION--' + '</li>');
}
```

should be executed if the app comes from being turned off?

would greatly appreciate your cooperation because my application should open a page distinct from index.html when notifications arrive and this is staying in the index.html

Here I'll edit my question to place a text fragment in the  [original plugin documentation](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) refers to the variable "coldstart":

> **Finally, should you completely exit the app by hitting the back button
>   from the home page, you may still receive a notification. Touching
>   that notification in the notification tray will relaunch your app and
>   allow you to process the notification (COLDSTART). In this case the
>   coldstart flag will be set on the incoming event.**

Also add my own code that opens a new page when receiving a push-notification:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent();
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function() {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        pushNotification.register(app.successHandler, app.errorHandler,{"senderID":"My sender ID","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});        
    },
 // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    successHandler: function(result) {
       alert('Callback Success! Result = '+result)
    },
    errorHandler:function(error) {
        alert(error);
    },
    onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    console.log("Regid " + e.regid);
                    window.localStorage.setItem("gcmid", e.regid);
                }
            break; 
    case 'message':
        // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
        // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
        if ( e.foreground )
        {
    alert('foreground message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt+' room= '+e.payload.room_msg+' lat = '+lat_r+' lng = '+lng_r);         
    top.location.href="chat.html?idu=notapply&room_snd=notapply&roomname_snd=" + e.payload.room_msg + "&lat_snd=" + lat_r + "&lng_snd=" + lng_r + "&msg_snd=" + e.message;
        }
        else
        {  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
            if ( e.coldstart )
            {
    alert('foreground message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt+' room= '+e.payload.room_msg+' lat = '+lat_r+' lng = '+lng_r);         
    top.location.href="chat.html?idu=notapply&room_snd=notapply&roomname_snd=" + e.payload.room_msg + "&lat_snd=" + lat_r + "&lng_snd=" + lng_r + "&msg_snd=" + e.message;
            }
            else
            {
     alert('foreground message = '+e.message+' msgcnt = '+e.msgcnt+' room= '+e.payload.room_msg+' lat = '+lat_r+' lng = '+lng_r);         
    top.location.href="chat.html?idu=notapply&room_snd=notapply&roomname_snd=" + e.payload.room_msg + "&lat_snd=" + lat_r + "&lng_snd=" + lng_r + "&msg_snd=" + e.message;
            }
        }
    break; 
            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break; 
            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
        }
    }
};
```

Solve my problem temporarily adding an additional payload which indicates to my activity which should open a page distinct from index.html, although the solution does not make "e.coldstart" is passed as "true,"  I add that to function in PushHandlerAtivity.java:

After:

```
private void forceMainActivityReload()
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent launchIntent =    pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());  
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Before:

```
private void forceMainActivityReload()
{
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getApplicationContext().getPackageName());       

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    launchIntent.putExtra("room_msg", extras.getString("room_msg"));

    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

of course in the function that generates the notification use **addDataWithKeyValue** function to add additional payload, then my main activity add the following:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            String message = extras.getString("room_msg");
             if(message != null){
                    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/chat.html?", 10000);         
                }else{
                    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
                }
```

Comment: When app in background, JS not working(stoping). So that it not exec

Comment: When in backgroudn works perfectly @HanhLe, the problem is when fully off, I assume the pushplugin starts app and then runs JS function "onNotificationGCM (e)"

Comment: oh, When your app is fully off then e.coldstart will not working if you tap notification to launching app. Because, your app off, that mean all resource will not working( except service backgound Android, it receive message and notification).

Comment: Ok @HanhLe, then another question arises, which applies to "e.coldstart"?

Comment: "e.coldstart" that mean your app start and Push plugin not created, Can you post your code, i will find exactly point

Comment: are you sure that that the term refers e.coldstart? because if we look at the [official documentation of the plugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) that says:
  **"Finally, should you completely exit the app by hitting the back button from the home page, you may still receive a notification. Touching that notification in the notification tray will relaunch your app and allow you to process the notification (COLDSTART). In this case the coldstart flag will be set on the incoming event."**

Comment: When your app off then message received will be cached notification, when you open notification then it send to JS with e.coldstart is true

Comment: Hi @RaulObagi, have you found the solution? I've experienced the same thing and until now I haven't found the solution. To make it happens (action after clicking notif bar), I did add code "pushNotification.register()", but it shouldn't be there since we didn't deal with GCM registration.

Answer (score 0):

My english is not good. To ensure PushPlugin working good, you should have a test case in Java to make sure plugin run correct or you have a mistake. When you touch in notification, PushHandlerActivity will be call, a it call function:

```
private void processPushBundle(boolean isPushPluginActive)
{
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        Bundle originalExtras = extras.getBundle("pushBundle");

        originalExtras.putBoolean("foreground", false);
        originalExtras.putBoolean("coldstart", !isPushPluginActive);

        PushPlugin.sendExtras(originalExtras);
    }
}
```

to identify your app in background or app is closed( in case it fired coldstart-->true)

**Edit 1:** coldstart true when your app is closed(not in background) and you click into notification to lauch app. When your app in background then coldstart still false. You can hack code by change variable 'isPushPluginActive'=true in above function.

Comment: Sorry for my english, I'm from Caracas Venezuela and try using google translator, in fact I've done these tests, as you can look out at first commented that notifications work perfectly, these are displayed in the status bar and when touched open my app, then, as the case show labels **INLINE NOTIFICATION** (when the app is foreground) or **BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION** (when the app is background), but when the app is closed (touching the back button) only open the app but the variable "coldstart = true" is not passed and therefore does not trigger the condition (if coldstart)

Comment: this function you posted (by the way I have spent three days analyzing) only works when the app is in the background but not in coldstart.

Comment: Sr, my english is not good. Ok, i will have a test case for you tomorrow. I very busy so that i not have a answer right now

Comment: ohh sorry now I understand, well, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Hi RaulObagi and @HanhLe, have you found answer about this issue? I have this issue too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can solve your problem

https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/issues/179